# CodeIgniter URI segments captured as variables?

Tags: php, codeigniter

well, i have a function within a controller called test, and i can access it by going to `http://localhost/nwk/control/test`

this is my function. I want to use the data given in the next segment from the "test" as a php variable.

so if i put

`function test()
  {
    $var =  $this->uri->segment(3);
    echo $var;
  }`

according to the user guide if I enter control/test/data, my variable should be equal to 'data'?

doesn't seem to be working.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason me autoloading the URI library made this whole functionality not work.

Everything is fine now. Thanks everyone.

Comment: That's because you don't need to load URI library yourself, it is initialized automatically. Glad you figured this out :)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the assignment operator

```
function test() { $var = $this->uri->segment(3); echo $var; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply make like this:

```
function test($var, $another_var)
{
    echo $var.' '.$another_var;
}
```

And opening http://localhost/nwk/control/test/it/works would echo "it works"

Comment: bassneck is right. It is better to use function arguments than uri segments. Try his example more carefully. It is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['name'] = $this->uri->segment(3, 0);
echo $name;
```

Comment: Keeps telling me that $name is unassigned. When it clearly is. Even if I just put `$name = $this->uri->segment(3, 0);` it still doesn't work. Just returns 0